# Article has margin: 0px not works?

Tags: html, css

Article has this attributes

```
section article {
    position: relative;
    width: 33.333333333%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

But I can see gap between images, why?

Whole code is here http://codepen.io/marciapn/pen/YyWWxL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the display to block and add float:left; and add an overflow hidden to the section

```
  section article {
        position: relative;
        width: 33.333333333%;
        display: block;
        float:left;
        margin: 0px;
  }
  section {
        overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this effect is to float all of the elements to the left and change the `display` to `block`. You should also set `overflow` to `hidden` on the parent element to expand it's height to contain all article elements inside it.

```
section {
    overflow:hidden;
}
section article {
    position: relative;
    width: 33.333333333%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) explains why this happens. It's because inline-block sees the spaces between the elements in your HTML code. There are multiple solutions.

### Remove spaces

You can literally remove the space between the elements in your code, for example like this:

```
<article>
  <img src="http://i1.wp.com/www.traveltipsor.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/helicopter-tours-Paris.jpg?resize=350%2C200" alt="">
  <nav class="info">
    <a href="">Things to do</a>
    <a href="">Flights</a>
    <a href="">Hotels</a>
    <a href="">Cars</a>
  </nav>
</article

><article>
  <img src="https://i1.wp.com/travelioo.com/img/Paris-Photo7.jpg?resize=350%2C200" alt="">
  <nav class="info">
    <a href="">Things to do</a>
    <a href="">Flights</a>
    <a href="">Hotels</a>
    <a href="">Cars</a>
  </nav>
</article>
```

However, this doesn't remove the spaces between each row of items.

### Negative Margin

You can set a negative margin with -4px, which may need to be adjusted to font-size. This solution can be problematic in older versions of IE, like 6 and 7, but doesn't mess up your code.

```
section article {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.333333333%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

### `Font-size: 0px;`

Just set `font-size` to `0px` and set them to the initial value in elements with text. This makes the spaces go away, because they heve no width.

This method isn't fully supported in Android.

### Use a different `display` value

There are plenty other options to use instead of `inline-block`, depending on what you want to do with it.